# JBoss EAP 6 / AS 7 deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, ear

After I copy the EAR in the deployments folder, it got deployed, but after ~ 5 seconds the EAR got undeployed again and a `XY.ear.failed` file is generated. 
When I touch the EAR, the same happens again. I can see nothing in the log(only that the ear is deployed/undeployed).
When I delete the `XY.ear.failed` file, the EAR will be deployed correctly, but the `XY.ear.failed` file is generated again.

Comment: If a `.failed` file is generated, then it means that the deployment failed. A good approach would be to stop the server, copy the .ear file to deployment folder, start the server and observer the log. You can find the exact reason why the deployment is failing.

Comment: It means deployment is failing.

Comment: it mean some part or EAR file isn't deployed, what lead to mark all EAR deployment as fail. Check logs, i am sure you find errors.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem once and the two problems i found and changed were :

1. Re-Compiled the classes(if any) in the deployed application
2. Checking the versions of the jars.